# How can I install Linux OS on my new Windows laptop?

Tags: linux, windows, distribution-choice

I am so eager to start using Linux on my new windows laptop. But I know no where to start.
In summary, I know some basic command which are being used in linux operating system such as sudo, su, netstat etc. But the problem is I don't know how to setup linux operating system on my new windows laptop. Please I need your contributions.

Comment: The search engine of your choice would be a good starting point.

Comment: The Windows Store has a few Linux distros that run in WSL2. Advantage: It works out of the box after two or three mouse clicks; no need to learn about network attachment or installation. Disadvantage: It's not quite a full Linux experience, and some work is required if you want a Linux GUI, but for a start, it's very useful. A virtual machine launched with VirtualBox or Vmware is slightly more difficult; it forces you to install Linux and think about how you attach the VM to the network.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You will have noticed that some contributors have issued downvotes on your question to indicate it could need improvement. One of the main reasons is that you ask it in a very broad way that is considered to lack sufficient "focus" for a question on this site. Perhaps you could start by making it more specific: (1) How do you want to use Linux - As a separate OS in parallel to your Windows installation (a.k.a "dual-boot"), or a Linux environment running under Windows (e.g. Windows Subsystem for Linux/"WSL2")? ...

Comment: ... (2) What will you mainly use Linux for (i.e. what does the Linux distribution have to offer/support)? (3) Do you have any previous experience in using Linux (i.e. do you need a very "beginner-friendly" distribution)? Please think about these points, and then edit your post to include specific requirements, which will make it much easier for contributors to offer guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a distributon (best is the one your friends or nearby friendly geeks use, you *will* need their help sooner or later), go to their webpage (Google is your friend!), there you'll find instructions.

Keep on the trodden path! Use some newbie-friendly, popular distribution like [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com) or [Fedora](https://getfedora.org) (my own preference, as it is mostly compatible with [RHEL](https://www.redhat.com/en), the distribution most often used "in earnest"; another option in this space is [CentOS](https://www.centos.org)), or perhaps [Debian](https://www.debian.org) (famous for it's extensive software offerings, base of more user-oriented Ubuntu).